# Flex: how to put project on web

Tags: apache-flex

I am new to flex and web programming. I created a canvas that I want to put on the web. What are the steps to do it?

I use a mac and I am using Fetch to put files.

Much thanks.

Comment: what kind of web setup do you have? technically, you can just dump a .swf someplace available to a browser, at least to test...

Comment: I am trying to put stuff in my home page in my school's server? There's a www folder so I think I put stuff in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you'll just export a release build from Flash Builder and then FTP the files to a web server.  ( Just like when you want to upload any other web page).

If you want to embed the generated SWF inside another HTML page, take a look at the generated html template and copy the appropriate code from the generated file into your other file, as appropriate.